# Simulating stealth address construction with JavaScript

Tags: cryptonote, stealth-address

I am trying to build an exercise. I want to produce a random 256-bit seed to give as an input for creating a Monero stealth address.

1) What are the restrictions on this seed in practice? I know it must be a legitimate scalar, but is that satisfied by it being 256-bit length? Can it be any random 256-bit number? If not, is there a javascript library for that calculation?

2) I have to write this exercise's grading program in nodejs (it is part of a bigger project). Does anyone know where I can find a javascript library that supports the needed calculations? (e.g. keccak, bytes_to_words, words_to_bytes, sc_reduce32, private_key_to_public_key).

For reference, the process for the calculation of a Monero stealth address is explained [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/constructing-a-stealth-monero-address/1501#1501) very well.

Answer (score 2):

1) Private keys are a randomly chosen 256-bit number mod *l*. *l* being `2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493`.

2) All the functions needed are in the source files of [the site](https://xmr.llcoins.net/) linked in the questions answer you linked to. Just use your browser debugger to access them.