# Building an integrated address from a regular address and old-style payment ID

Tags: payment-id, integrated-address

I have a bot for automated sending of XMR. The bot can send XMR to integrated addresses only, without separate payment ID support.

One customer has given me both a regular address and an old-style long payment ID.  I have no feedback with this customer and I can't ask him to generate an integrated address or short payment ID.

I know an integrated address is made from a regular address and short payment ID, but the customer gave me a long payment ID. Is it possible to create an integrated address, which corresponds to a given pair? Otherwise, is it possible to convert the long payment ID to a short payment ID?

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on how *long* the supplied payment ID is. Integrated addresses embed a short payment ID (64 bits - 8 bytes). So if the supplied payment ID is 8 bytes or less, yes, you can construct an integrated address using the supplied regular address and payment ID. Steps would be:

1. Base58 decode the regular address
2. Replace the first byte with byte 0x13
3. Remove the last 4 bytes
4. Append the payment ID (padded to 8 bytes if it's shorter)
5. Append the first 4 bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the above
6. Base58 encode - this result is the integrated address.

You could alternatively just use the wallet RPC method [make_integrated_address](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address) passing in the parameters `standard_address` and `payment_id`.

If the supplied payment ID is *longer* than 8 bytes, then no, you cannot create an integrated address using that payment ID and address.

Comment: The received payment_id is 32 bytes. Is it impossible anyway?

Comment: "If the supplied payment ID is longer than 8 bytes, then no, you cannot create an integrated address using that payment ID and address."

Comment: It is worth noting the **Base58 decode** of a **Monero primary address** is atypical when compared to many other cryptos, there are nine separate fields see the bottom answer of https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/constructing-a-stealth-monero-address.

Comment: A clearer explanation of the variant of the base58 implementation used in Monero can be found [here](https://monerodocs.org/cryptography/base58/).