# How can I get the right Keccak-256 tools. The online tool seems wrong...?

Tags: privatekey, spend-key

I want to test this StackExchange [Q/A](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/constructing-a-stealth-monero-address).

which got 889DA12A88D36BCE0966AB1A79125779DD1F2FC6F1145DE131FD52A5B468796D from

```
% keccak -256 198584347013dd91832be3d82529437db7cc8e1850e559cdd3872b29ca819601
```

However, when I use the Keccak-256 online tool found here:
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

I get: `11d0c17e049fd25f195a6b3694d37658240961d55f263cca40f2c5f91e6fac2d`

The results are not the same. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online tool works perfectly, but the form accepts text and you were pasting in hex. The ASCII string `"198584347013dd91832be3d82529437db7cc8e1850e559cdd3872b29ca819601"` is `31393835383433343730313364643931383332626533643832353239343337646237636338653138353065353539636464333837326232396361383139363031` in hex, and the online tool correctly produced a keccak256 hash of the hex of what you pasted in.

The result of your `keccak -256` command is also correct.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it.. If I past "31393835383433343730313364643931383332626533643832353239343337646237636338653138353065353539636464333837326232396361383139363031" to the online tool, I still can't get the right answer.

Comment: It shows a0aad49db54af4cfb5de9fb29a37131ccf1051a1068c190a4a5fd07c369c8681.
But the answer is 889DA12A88D36BCE0966AB1A79125779DD1F2FC6F1145DE131FD52A5B468796D

Comment: @Mooooo The online tool cannot accept hex, it can only accept ascii. But your keccak command line tool can accept hex, so you'll see that if you do `keccak -256 31393835383433343730313364643931383332626533643832353239343337646237636338653138353065353539636464333837326232396361383139363031` the answer will be `11d0c17e049fd25f195a6b3694d37658240961d55f263cca40f2c5f91e6fac2d `, exactly the same as the online tool reported.